# How do I vertically center the text in a <li> without affecting the list bullet?

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I am trying to build a simple website, the HTML is like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="l1">Test item 1</li>
    <li class="l2">Test item 2</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

You can see the text does not align with the bullets.
Here is what I tried:

```
ul{
  display: table;
}
```

and

```
li{
  display: table-cell;
  text-align:middle;
}
```

But the bullets disappeared:
[image]

So I wanna ask if there are any ways to vertical center the text in the list item  without affecting the bullets?

Comment: could you please give us a demo that shows the mis-alignment?

Comment: Can you please make a jsfiddle for this or you can use text-align:center;

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to center relatively to what else? The text contents relatively to the `li`? The `li` relatively to the `ul`?

Comment: I tried to clarify my requirement, hope it is clear enough.

Comment: OK, now it's clear, but how do you  display these icons?

Comment: I use local images with list-style-image property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only list-items have [markers](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#marker-pseudo):

> The `::marker` pseudo-element represents the automatically generated
>   marker box of a list item. (See [`display: list-item`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#marker-pseudo).)

So you need [`list-item`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#list-items):

> The `list-item` keyword causes the element to generate a
>   [`::marker`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#selectordef-marker) pseudo-element box with the content specified by its
>   [list-style](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#propdef-list-stylehttp://) properties ([CSS 2.1§12.5 Lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#lists)) together with a
>   principal box of the specified type for its own contents.

CSS Display 3 introduces some variants of `list-item`:

```css
list-item block flow
list-item block flow-root
list-item inline flow
list-item inline flow-root
list-item run-in flow
list-item run-in flow-root
```

but it seems there is no browser support, so better use the old `display: list-item`.

That's why, if you use `display: inline-block` or `display: table-cell`, the markers disappear.

If you want to align the markers vertically, the [CSS Lists and Counters drafts](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#marker-pseudo-element) allows

```css
li::marker {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

However, don't expect any browser to support this yet. Instead, I would recommend hiding the markers and using a `::before` pseudo-element instead:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li::before {
  content: url('image.ico');
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Note the behavior will be like if you used `list-style-position: inside`, which may not look right if the list items have line breaks. You can try absolute positioning if you want to emulate `list-style-position: outside`.

Comment: ```list-style-position: inside``` worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

Revised answer:

looking at the images you've provided, the problem may be with the icon. If you re-crop the image with less empty space at the bottom, it may align correctly.

The icon, by default, will vertically align according to line-height. If it's larger than the line height, you end up with incorrect alignment.

Try adjusting the line height in your css for the li to be the same height as the icon. 
If there is empty space at the bottom of the icon, crop it out.

Or recreate your icon to be the same height as your line height, and try to remove all extra space in the image.

Comment: This centers horizontally, not vertically.